# -Djava.security.policy for force use of our policy file

Tags: java, security, applet

I want my applet to use policy file created under `user.home/.java.policy`. I'm confused what is the proper argument to use that policy file?

```
-Djava.security.policy=file:${user.home}/.java.policy
```

Or

```
-Djava.security.policy=file:///${user.home}/.java.policy
```

Or

```
-Djava.security.policy={user.home}/.java.policy
```

Or

```
-Djava.security.policy=({user.home}/.java.policy)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above. The ones that are legal syntax will all be evaluated by the JSP at the server, using the *server* user's home directory *at the server.* None of them gives a URL relative to the applet user's home directory on the client machine. In any case you can't use the `-Djava.security.policy` form in an applet anyway, at least outside the `appletviewer.` You have to use the JWS syntax.

Comment: Can you help me with this SOT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401951/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-security-securityperm/19407596?noredirect=1#comment28804373_19407596 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424410/changing-java-policy-file-for-applet

Comment: I don't know what SOT means, but have you considered signing the applet?

Comment: SOT: StackOverflow Thread. I tried applet signed using `.pfx` certificate. but not working

Comment: TLA: Three Letter Acronym. We have enough already. Don't invent more, and if you do, don't expect everybody else to know what you're talking about. Don't forget to answer the actual question I asked, instead of perpetrating this futile and irrelevant digression.