# Impact of System.setSecurityManager(null)

Tags: java, security, applet

I was facing some issue in Applet. Here is the links for that issue.

[java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "authProvider.SunMSCAPI")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401951/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-security-securityperm)

I just added `System.setSecurityManager(null)` And my applet works fine. I want to know, what will be the impact of settings security manager to null? Will it make data insecure? or something else.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are talking about applet

From docs of [Security manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html)

> Typically, a web applet runs with a security manager provided by the browser or Java Web Start plugin. Other kinds of applications normally run without a security manager, unless the application itself defines one. If no security manager is present, the application has no security policy and acts without restrictions.

So by passing null, you are disabling security for your run time environment.

*For example*, **System.exit**, which terminates the Java virtual machine with an exit status, invokes SecurityManager.checkExit to ensure that the current thread has permission to shut down the application.

There are some more examples too that what happens If you disable security manager like file permissions etc.

Please read the full docs before making it `null`, Because of that you are welcoming security issues in your application as well as to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the security manager in an applet is a really bad idea. If the applet has that permission, then it can do anything as the local user anyway. However, once you clear the security manager that becomes true of all code running in that process, including unsigned applets from other sites. Any applet (signed with a valid certificate) that clears the security manager should be blacklisted.