# security exception when running java application outside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, tomcat7, birt

I'm developing java web application using birt, when I run the application from eclipse it works as expected, but when I run it from netbeans or when I deploy it manually on tomcat , it bugs

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: securityDomain should be null if setSecurityController() was never called
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2340)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1359)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1348)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine$3.run(JavascriptEngine.java:240)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine$3.run(JavascriptEngine.java:1)
```

how to fix it please?

Answer (score 2):

I reported this as critical [bug 429944](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429944) a few days ago, you should vote for it in bugzilla.

As far as i know, there are 2 possible workarounds:

**Option 1:** If possible disable the security management of your Tomcat server. By default it is disabled, but it seems in your context it is not. Check if argument "-security" is used to start Tomcat, and try to remove it.

**Option 2:** as suggested in the bug description there are two methods that should be changed in the source code of birt for a quick fix.

Comment: I disabled the security manager, but the open source library net.nicholaswilliams.java.licensing, that I use in my project create a new one, that's why the exception persist

Comment: In that case, since the securityManager cannot be disabled in this licensing library, im afraid you need to patch BIRT as mentionned in the bugzilla link i joined. Or may be patch the licensing library to prevent it to create a SecurityManager

Comment: I can confirm that following the recommendation on [bug 429944 comment 7](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429944#c7) works fine. I am using the exact same verson of the BIRT runtime JAR the OP indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `System.setSecurityManager(null);` in to your code before you call the report. You should only need to do this once per JVM instance.

Comment: But you also need to consider the impact of setting it to `null`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487407/impact-of-system-setsecuritymanagernull.

Comment: @radimpe - the link talks only about applets - I'd assumed that this was server side only. You're right though, if this is an applet, switching off the security manager is a bad idea. If it's server side,  you still need to consider what effect ( if any ) explicitly switching off the security manager would have, but in my experience, the majority of web apps tend not to run with a security manager enabled

Comment: thanks for your reply,
I'm trying your solution and now I've a new bug

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Setting a SecurityManager other than the LicenseSecurityManager is prohibited.
 at net.nicholaswilliams.java.licensing.LicenseSecurityManager.checkPermission(LicenseSecurityManager.java:260)

Comment: have you added the net.nicholaswilliams.java packages your self, or are they part of birt?

Comment: I've added it my self

Comment: Well it looks like using that LicenseSecurityManager conflicts with using BIRT. I don;t have any suggestions except toperhaps go back to the developer of the LicenceSecurityManager and see if they can shed any light on it. Or see if this helps : https://java.nicholaswilliams.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=539

Answer (score 1):

you should not deactivate the security manager !
a hint here to bypass the error :

```
Context context = Context.enter( );
context.setSecurityController( ScriptUtil.createSecurityController( ) );
```

these two lines should resolve the issue. I found that in `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngineFactory` class file, so basically you would prefer a call directly to the class `JavascriptEngineFactory` to initialize everything in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I use birt runtime 4.2.2 instead of using  the  4.3.1 version ,
every thing work fine now, even without disabling security manager.
thank you, all of you for your help