# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:8081 connect,resolve) - main reasons

Tags: java, security, applet

What are the main reasons that cause the exception reported?

Same trusted signed applet (Digicert certificate), works great on some PCs, doesn't work on other. Exception occurs when i try to get an attachment stream through `URLConnection`

Where it doesn't works, i resolve with

```
grant { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission; 
};
```

in

```
java.policy
```

but i would like to avoid to update every PC.

Could be a `port` (8081) issue? What should I investigate?

Comment: It isn't a port 8081 issue, it is a certificate issue. The PCs on which it doesn't work don't trust or haven't accepted the signing certificate. Is it issued by a Certificate Authority?

Comment: Yes, jar is signed by a Certificate Authority. PC has accepted the certificate

Answer (score 2):

> Same trusted signed applet (Digicert certificate), works great on some PCs, doesn't work on other.

It isn't trusted by those other PCs, and wasn't accepted by the user as trusted when asked.

OR

> This is my manifest.mf

```
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Name: MyApp
Name: MyName
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_16 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Main-Class: MyClass
Codebase: *
```

If that's the complete manifest, this JAR isn't signed at all, let alone by a trusted certificate. It should be full of `Name:` and `SHA-256-Digest` entries.

Answer (score 1):

go to path of java jdk and ./jre/lib/security/
open java policy file

then set the grant permission for SocketPermission
`grant{
permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:8080", "connect,resolve";
}`
 then restart and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Writing custom `SecurityManager` for your applet could solve your issue. Setting your own `SecurityManager` will grant all permission for your applet.

```
class customSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

        SecurityManager original;

        customSecurityManager(SecurityManager original) {
            this.original = original;
        }

        /**
         * Deny permission to exit the VM.
         */
        public void checkExit(int status) {
            //throw(new SecurityException("Not allowed"));
        }

        /**
         * Allow this security manager to be replaced, if fact, allow pretty
         * much everything.
         */
        public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
        }

        public SecurityManager getOriginalSecurityManager() {
            return original;
        }
    }
```

Now set this security manager for your applet

```
public void init() {
   customSecurityManager cSM = new customSecurityManager(System.getSecurityManager());
   System.setSecurityManager(cSM);
}
```

**Caution**: [Impact of System.setSecurityManager(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487407/impact-of-system-setsecuritymanagernull)

Comment: If he doesn't have permission to open a socket he certainly won't have permission to change the security manager.

Comment: If you set a security manager, you set it for all the applets in the process. Probably not a good idea. In general, you want to avoid globals.

Answer (score 0):

You must add "all-permissions" in manifest.mf instance "sandbox"

and

sign your jar file with code signing certificate.

Comment: As i said, jar file is signed with Digicert Certificate. This is my manifest.mf `Trusted-Library: true
Application-Name: MyApp
Name: MyName
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_16 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Main-Class: MyClass
Codebase: *`

Comment: Your jar file is signed by sun?

Comment: No, by DigiCert. Do you mean that i have to remove the line "Created by..." ?

Comment: No my friend. find same jar without sign. and sign by other certificate.

Comment: and use this solution:
public void method() {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

        public Object run() {
            // It will work if your applet is signed
            callWeb();
            return null;
        }

    });

}

private void callWeb() {

}

Comment: Command that cause the problem is just in a Privileged block. But, sorry, why should I sign up with another certificate? My question is more general: why in a PC i have the problem and not in another one? What to investigate?

Comment: I had a same problem with this certificate. 
Sun Microsystems Inc.
And I have to sign by my self certificate.
So test privileged block if problem does not solve sign that by other certificate.

Comment: I think that could a problem related to something on PC (user rights or something else, that's why it doesn't happen on every PC), but i can't figure it out. I use Digicert certificate to accomplish with JRE 1.7 requirements, i used originally a self certificate.