# Oauth : Google Api : access denied

Tags: java, google-api

I am developing few REST webservices using Java Servlet. I would like to use google OAuth2 for authenticating my client and use oauth token for exposing my webservices.

As per the guideline on following url: [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

For Web Apps I followed below steps:

1. Registered my application with [Google development console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0).
2. Created new `Client ID` and `Client secret`.

After that I have used below Google authentication end point to generate authorization code on server: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`

With query parameter define here: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl)

Response of above URL gives me authorization code as query paramters, I use that code to generate oauth Token using https connection.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

Query parameters are

- code
- client_id
- client_secret
- redirect_uri
- grant_type

When I call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token service to generate oauth token from server, I am getting Java Exception.

*java.security.AccessControlException:* *access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "www.googleapis.com:443" "connect,resolve")*

Please help me if I missing any configuration or am doing something wrong.

[image: Permission at google developer console]

Comment: [This](https://github.com/alfasin/Google-Admin-Directory-API) might be helpful.

Comment: see this stackoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074623/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-1).

Comment: Do you have anything against using the Google java client library really would make your life easer.  https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

Comment: @DaImTo , i think the url you provided might help, but it have too much information, I am not getting what exactly i need to use.My intention is, to let the end user authenticate with google and my server api will create the oauth token.

Comment: @DaImTo, after implementing JAVA Client Lib, I am getting : Java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")

Comment: Thanks !! I figure out that I need to add permissions in tomcat catalina.policy file.